# Vertical text centering in fluid parent and child div

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
div#all {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}

div#left {
    width: 47%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
div.box span {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img#right {
    width: 53%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="left">

        <span>
        My long text bla bla bla sadf asdfasdfasd fasdf asdfsadfasdf
        </span>


    </div>

    <img id="right" src="http://asset3.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/09/19/35446285_620x433.jpg">
</div>
```

And I am getting this:

[image]

However I want to center the text part like this:

[image]

How to do such thing?

**IMPORTANT 1!** The vertical text needs to adjust to one line or multiple lines and center that vertically dynamically.

**IMPORTANT 2!** Everything needs to be fluid! Only % is allowed, no px,pt,em etc. !

**HERE IS ALSO JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/GkF6R/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/w8NzK/)...

***CSS:***

```
div#all {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: blue;
   position: relative;
}

div span {
   width: 40%;
   background: red;
   padding-left: 10%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

img#right {
   width: 50%;
   height: auto;

   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div id="all">
    <span>
    My long text bla bla bla sadf asdfasdfasd fasdf asdfsadfasdf
    </span><img id="right" src="http://asset3.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/09/19/35446285_620x433.jpg">
</div>
```

Is that what you want?

One really important thing- `<img>` tag must be just right after `</span>`. Without spacebar or enter. This is because both elements are inline-block. If you place 'space' or 'enter' the layout will not work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working when I use my original structure and float attributes. They need to be present, because my design is a little bit more difficult than what I put here.

Comment: Seems t owork when there is no space and I can remove float a nd it works too ;) Thanks.

Comment: Great :) With space it won't work because you have 50% width on span and 50% width on img. Space is also added to width so it's more than 100% then. That is why there souldn't be any character between this two tags.

Answer (score 0):

[Does this work for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/GkF6R/4/)

**CSS Snippet**

```
div span {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but if the text is more than one line it is broken check this: http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/GkF6R/4/ ;(. I will update my post so it is clear from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're close to a tabular layout, use the tables vs trying to manipulate `<span>` and `<div>` into a table

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkF6R/28/)

CSS

```css
#all {border-collapse:collapse;background:blue;width:100%;}
#all .desc {width:49%;max-width:49%;vertical-align:middle;}
#all .desc p {background:green;text-align:center;}
#all .img {width:51%;line-height:0;font-size:0;}
#all img {width:100%;}
```

HTML

```
<table id="all">
    <tr>
        <td class="desc">
            <p>My long text bla bla bla sadf asdfasdfasd fasdf asdfsadfasdf</p>
        </td>
        <td class="img">
            <img src="http://asset3.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/09/19/35446285_620x433.jpg">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess is that it's for using a table for layout instead of tabular data. There are more semantic ways to markup this content, but I don't think that a table is one of them.